# Need help on SQL query to traverse table dependencies

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a bit of help on SQL query to traverse table dependencies.  For now my query only retrieves up to two levels; however, I need to go to the last leaf in the dependency table tree.

Here is my query:

```
declare @tableName varchar(64);
set @tableName = 'ServiceRequests';

WITH TblPath (ParentTableName, ParentTableId, ParentColumnName, ReferencedTableName,  ReferencedTableId, ReferencedColumnName, Lvl)
AS (
 -- Anchore
select
     SO_P.name
     ,SO_P.object_id
     ,SC_P.name
     ,SO_R.name
     ,FKC.referenced_object_id
     ,SC_R.name
    ,1 -- level
from sys.foreign_key_columns FKC
     inner join sys.objects SO_P on SO_P.object_id = FKC.parent_object_id
     inner join sys.columns SC_P on ((SC_P.object_id = FKC.parent_object_id) AND (SC_P.column_id = FKC.parent_column_id))
     inner join sys.objects SO_R on SO_R.object_id = FKC.referenced_object_id
     inner join sys.columns SC_R on ((SC_R.object_id = FKC.referenced_object_id) AND (SC_R.column_id = FKC.referenced_column_id))
where 
((SO_P.name = @tableName) AND (SO_P.type = 'U'))
OR
((SO_R.name = @tableName) AND (SO_R.type = 'U'))

-- Recursive call
UNION ALL
select
   SO_P.name
  ,SO_P.object_id
  ,SC_P.name
  ,SO_R.name
  ,FKC.referenced_object_id
  ,SC_R.name
  ,lvl + 1 -- level
from sys.foreign_key_columns FKC
   inner join sys.objects SO_P on SO_P.object_id = FKC.parent_object_id
   inner join sys.columns SC_P on ((SC_P.object_id = FKC.parent_object_id) AND (SC_P.column_id = FKC.parent_column_id))
   inner join sys.objects SO_R on SO_R.object_id = FKC.referenced_object_id
   inner join sys.columns SC_R on ((SC_R.object_id = FKC.referenced_object_id) AND (SC_R.column_id = FKC.referenced_column_id))
   inner join TblPath t on ((t.ParentTableId = FKC.referenced_object_id) )
where 
((SO_P.name = @tableName) AND (SO_P.type = 'U'))
OR
((SO_R.name = @tableName) AND (SO_R.type = 'U'))

)
select * from  TblPath
order by lvl desc
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20)
```

Comment: Most likely you will have to use cursors as much as you don't want to just because there are some self referencing tables which might not work out the way you want to.

Comment: There is no need for cursors. Just use the correct filters to cancel out the self referencing relations. One tip. I would use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views instead of directly querying the `sys` tables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this script:

```
DECLARE @Output TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),ParentTable INT, ReferencedTable INT, Recursion INT)

INSERT INTO @Output (ParentTable, ReferencedTable, Recursion)
SELECT DISTINCT
    fk.parent_object_id  ParentObject,
    fk.referenced_object_id ReferencedObject,
    1 as Recursion
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c1 ON fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c2 ON fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id AND fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) = 'YourTableNameHere'

DECLARE 
    @Recursion INT,
    @ReferencedTable INT,
    @CurrentID INT = 1,
    @MaxID INT

SET @MaxID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @Output)

WHILE (@CurrentID <= @MaxID)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @ReferencedTable = ReferencedTable
    FROM @Output WHERE ID = @CurrentID

    SELECT TOP 1 
        @Recursion = Recursion +1
    FROM @Output 
    WHERE ReferencedTable = @ReferencedTable
    ORDER BY Recursion ASC

    INSERT INTO @Output (ParentTable, ReferencedTable, Recursion)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        fk.parent_object_id  ParentObject,
        fk.referenced_object_id ReferencedObject,
        @Recursion
    FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c1 ON fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c2 ON fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id AND fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
    WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @ReferencedTable

    SET @MaxID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @Output)
    SET @CurrentID +=1
 END



SELECT DISTINCT
    OBJECT_NAME(ParentTable) AS ParentTable, 
    OBJECT_NAME(ReferencedTable) AS ReferencedTable,
    Recursion
FROM @Output ORDER BY Recursion ASC
```